# Writing an Android key logger by intercepting keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keylogger

**Background**

As a school project in a course in computer security, me  and a friend is going to try to write an Android key logger. After having a look at already existing solutions, we've come to the conclusion that most others do this by implementing a keyboard which is to replace the original. Preferably we'd like to avoid this solution.

**Question**

Is it possible to somehow intercept the Android keyboard, or must we find another solution? For instance, on a computer you could intercept the interrupts, but as the Android keyboard is a piece of software, are there any actual interrupts which might be useful for us?

Comment: On a computer you couldn't intercept the interrupts, because that's not something the kernel allows you to do. (Well, you could if you were the kernel, or part of the kernel, which is exactly what device drivers are on both Windows and Linux)

Comment: maybe write your own keyboard software ?

Comment: @immibis I am well aware of this, but according to my experience most PC key loggers use some kind of exploit to break into the kernel.

Comment: @Hacketo I said pretty specifically in the question that we wanted to avoid that solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: If you find an exploit to break into the kernel on a non-rooted phone, you've just won yourself the attention of every security researcher on Earth, and probably lots of monetary prizes.

Comment: @immibis So that is what it would take on an Android device as well then? Breaking into the kernel?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, you could write your own keyboard. (Also, while I personally don't mind giving you an idea in a comment, I don't think this question is a good question for SO. Also, I don't know anything about writing keyboard apps on Android)

Comment: @immibis Yes, it seems like this might be the easiest and most feasible way to go. And yes, perhaps android.se would've been a better place to ask than SO. But thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score -1):

There is diffrence between working of android keyboard and windows keyboard.

Windows : Keyboard work on hardware inerupts which can be detected.

Android : On android keyboard works by intercepting the touch events. 
Keyboard application attach a view to available window(WindowManagerService) displaying the keyboard layout for particular language.
Then user touch specific area of "albhabet" , window manager dispatches the touch event to keyboard application , which detects where user has touch by identifying 
the touch evnets co ordinates, then by after identification it sends "touched alphabet" to view(EditText for ex) which is bounded to keyboard via InputMethodManagerService
or custom keyboard service of installed application.

Permission of application as verified by user while installing it.

Hence keyboard application works in andorid works in sandbox and what it is doing side it cannot be detected by any
external application due to security feature of android.

Hence based on this I dont think you can detect any hardware interrupt unless untill device have available harware keyboard.